# Combine result of two functions in python

Tags: python

The objective I'm trying to reach is to take a string, extract time as hours and minutes and return them as degrees on an analogue clock dial, the only way i could think to do this is to create 2 functions, one to return the hours and another to return the minutes. I've probably gone about this the completely the wrong way (i'm a beginner). I now need to combine the result of two functions as a string. my code looks like this:

```
def clock_degree(s):
    hr, min = s.split(':')
    if int(hr) > 12:
        return str((int(hr)-12)*30)
    elif int(hr) == 0:
        return str((int(hr)+12)*30)
    elif int(hr) > 24:
        return "Check your time !"
    elif int(hr) < 0:
        return "Check your time !"
    else:
        return int(hr) * 30

def clock_degree_min(x):
    hour, mn = x.split(':')
    if int(mn) == 60:
        return 360
    elif int(mn) == 0:
        return 360
    elif int(mn) > 60:
        return "Check your time !"
    elif int(mn) < 0:
        return "Check your time !"
    else:
        return int(mn) * 6
```

any other solution to how i could achieve this is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run all the checks in one function and *return* both results in a *tuple*

Comment: isn't there a problem in your `int(hr) == 0` test?

Comment: You should have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_angle_problem for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer something like this that is a bit more terse:

```
def getDegrees(t):
    h, m = [float(n) for n in t.split(":")]
    result = []
    for n, denominator in (h, 12), (m, 60):
        result.append(str((n % denominator) / denominator * 360))
    return ",".join(result)
```

For both minutes and seconds, start with the maximum value and use it to get the modulus (e.g., 22->10) and then divide by it (6->0.5), then multiply by 360.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the times in a list, then you can do the following:

```
currentTimes = [] # Here's a list of times before the functions manipulate each element.

analogDialTimes = [(clock_degree(time), clock_degree_min(time)) for time in currentTimes]
```

This returns a list of tuples, similar to what Moses suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather avoid mixing return types (that's what exceptions are for), and use standard library functions for common operations like parsing time ([time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)):

```
import time
s="15:43"
t=time.strptime(s,"%H:%M")
pair = t.tm_hour*360/12, t.tm_min*360/60
```

Use modulo `t.tm_hour%12` if you want to restrict the hour hand to one turn, and combine hour and minute for a smoothly moving hour hand `(t.tm_hour+t.tm_min/60.0)`.

Finally, as to how to handle that pair, you said "combine the result of two functions as a string" but that doesn't tell me what sort of format you want it in. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
def clock_degree(s):
    hr, min = s.split(':')    
    hr = float(hr) + float(min)/60 # convert minutes to hours (ex : 30 min = 0.5h)
    hr = hr % 12 # have a time between 0:00 and 12:00
    angle = (360 / 12) * hr # calculate the angle (6h => 180°)
    print(hr, angle)
    return (hr, angle)

clock_degree('24:00')
clock_degree('12:00')
clock_degree('6:00')
clock_degree('24:30')
```

outputs :

```
0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
6.0 180.0
0.5 15.0
```